# Editing misspellings

Tags: discusión, ediciones

I know that editing for typos or misspellings should be avoided in Stack Exchange sites. However, as this is a language site, I find dangerous to leave some mistakes in Spanish that could lead to learners to make them. For example, in this question [Why is a comma used before a "y" in some cases?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/719/why-comma-is-used-before-a-y-in-some-cases) there is a mistake in this sentence:

> Al exámen tengo que llevar lápiz, pluma y borrador.

*Exámen* has no tilde: *examen*. Actually, this is a common mistake among Spanish speakers and I don't think it's a good idea to leave it like this because a learner of Spanish could read it and start writing it like that (wrong).

What should we do in this cases? Edit the question/answer and leave a comment, or just leave a comment? I saw in other language forums that the community usually tells mistakes and I think we should do so.

Comment: The distinction that should be noted is that edits of less than a couple of characters (6, specifically) are considered too insignificant.  *That*, I believe, is the point of this question--or should be.  What do we do about questions with 1 missing accent?  (As a side note, I think all the answers still apply.)

Comment: We suggest taking a long, hard look at the [editing privileges wiki](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit). :D

Comment: @Aarthi Exactly, my doubts came from this: 'Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, **not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.**'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No Joel, this is wrong, Stack Exchange encourages us to edit posts to improve them for spelling, grammar, readability, and formatting.

We're not supposed to change what the OP is saying though so personally I try to keep the style intact and only fix things that are actually broken. For instance I never change between multiple correct spellings such as British vs American spelling.

Comment: As I replied to @Aarthi above, in the editing wiki says to not just change a single character.

Comment: I think you're reading that a bit too literally but I also think it's poorly worded. They don't want trivial edits that add nothing but they do still want edits that fix a single character misspelling.

Answer (score 4):

Who ever said that it should be avoided? Whoever said that is wrong. :P

On every FAQ of every Stack Exchange site you'll see this

> [image]

So I'd say that, like hippietrail said, it's even *encouraged!!!* If you see a mistake, edit it. What you must be aware of, though, is that your changes shouldn't change the meaning originally conveyed by the OP. If your edits change that, then post a comment explaining your doubts. :)

Comment: Read from the above comments of the question about the editing privileges wiki.

Comment: @Joel If you're in doubt about your edit, then simply post a comment pointing the author to that part of his/her answer or question. Sometimes I see a dot missing at the end of a sentence. I always correct it... That's the most minor edit maybe, but a missing dot is not a minor mistake.

Comment: My first impulse was to leave a comment, but not enough rep :P

Comment: @Joel That's a small obstacle... In that case, you can annotate the post and wait for more reputation. You only need 50 for comments, so, you'll soon be able to post them. :D